# Как запустить программу которая требует root права

Tags: php, bash, shell, exec

Как запустить программ из php скрипта которая выполняется только из под sudo или root-a?

```
<?php
    exec('app -param1 -param2');
?>
```

В данном примере `app` правильно сработает только от root или из под sudo. А мне нужно ее запускать при обращении к серверу из браузера

Comment: Используйте sudo, у него в настройках можно задать какой пользователь может выполнять какую программу без запроса пароля. http://www.o-nix.com/pages/nix-tips-tricks/sudo-bez-parolja.php

Answer (score 1):

Все программы запускаемы интерпретатором PHP - выполняются с правами веб-сервера под которым они работают, можно дать веб-серверу неограниченные права, но за безопасность тогда сложно будет ручаться.

Comment: Действительно, давать рутовые права скрипту не безопасно, и главное, абсолютно не зачем. потому что ему можно дать права на выполнение одной единственной привилегированной программы через sudo.